# JQM without iframe

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, iframe

I try build app by JQM and I use widget Navbar, until now I used by IFrame but it works not good.
My question is, what can I replace instead of IFrame ?

```html
<div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example">
<ul>
<li>
<a  href="#info_tab" class="infoButton ui-btn-active" data-icon="custom" 
id="infoMenu">     </a></l`enter code here`i>
<li><a  href="#calendar_tab" class="calendarButton" 
data-icon="custom"  id="calendarMenu"></a></li>
<li><a   href="#picture_tab" class="picturesButton" data-icon="custom" 
id="pictureMenu">     </a></li>
<li><a  href="#buy_tab" class="buyButton" data-icon="custom" id="buyMenu"></a></li>
                </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End Navigation Bar -->
    <!-- iFrames -->
    <div  id="iFramesDIV">


<div id="info_tab" class="fullScreen ">        
            </div>
            <div id="calendar_tab" class="fullScreen hide"> 
    <iframe id="calendarFrame" src="tab_pickadate/calendar.html" 
     scrolling="no" frameborder="0"   class="fullScreen"></iframe>
            </div>
     <div id="picture_tab" class="fullScreen  hide">                
     <iframe id="pictureFrame" src="" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
     class="fullScreen"></iframe>         
            </div>        
            <div id="buy_tab" class="fullScreen  hide">
     <iframe id="buyFrame" src="tab_buy/buy.html" frameborder="0" 
      class="fullScreen"></iframe>
            </div>                  
        </div>
        <!-- End iFrames --> 
</div>
<!-- End Content-->
```

Please help me :)

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you need exactly?

Comment: I don't want to use by iframe
With what I can replace it ?

Answer (score 0):

To use iframes you will need to include JQM library in the source of Iframe. Try including JQM in "tab_pickadate/calendar.html" path. I also worked with Iframes and JQM together.